# subsonic stored procedure call timing out

Tags: subsonic

I am experiencing weird behavior when trying to call a stored procedure using subsonic from a website. I am getting "time out expired" error when I call the stored procedure using subsonic. If I execute the same stored procedure in sql server management studio, it runs instantly. I am not knowing what the problem is. I cannot step into the code because it is referenced as a dll.  I am using version 2.1. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks,
sridhar.

Comment: Is SSMS running on the same machine as the web site? Is the web site on the same server as the database? Do other SubSonic calls work? Have verified the connection string?

Comment: I am running ssms from my local computer. the database server is different from iis. the weird thing is the stored procedure runs fine with some parameters. for example the stored procedure runs fine for one employee. If I change the employee, it is giving time out error.

Comment: Without knowing the internals of the Sproc, there's probably not much guidance we can provide. It sounds like an issue with the queries in the sproc.

Comment: I figured out the problem. It is not related to subsonic. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It is my fault. I have a transaction open in the sql server management studio. Then I ran an update statement on a table. All the records affected by that update statement are locked because of transaction. it is working for some employees because those records are not locked. I ran the sp_who2 to determine the locked processes and figured out the problem.

Thanks,
sridhar.